# DB2 - Aggregate row data into comma list

Tags: sql, db2

i am reading a db2 table where the data is stored as

```
user    group  
-----   ------
user1   groupa  
user1   groupb  
user1   groupc  
user2   groupc  
user3   groupc
```

i want a single row returned for each user.

user1 groupa,groupb,groupc

i have been told by other forms the correct way to do this is below

```
SELECT VRAVW900_USER, SUBSTR(xmlserialize(xmlagg(xmltext(CONCAT( ', ',VRAVW900_Group))) as VARCHAR(1024)), 3) AS Groups
FROM VRADB2.VRAVW900 
GROUP BY VRAVW900_USER
```

This does not work for me and i get the error:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=VARCHAR;CLOB CHAR CHARACTER BLOB BINARY DBCLOB, DRIVER=3.64.133
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:679)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.bd.a(bd.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io.c(io.java:2706)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io.d(io.java:2694)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io.a(io.java:2143)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io.a(io.java:2119)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.h(ab.java:136)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.b(ab.java:41)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.a(p.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.qb.i(qb.java:135)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io.gb(io.java:2112)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io.a(io.java:3191)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io.a(io.java:686)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io.executeQuery(io.java:669)
    at com.service_now.monitor.jdbc.JDBCRowSet.query(JDBCRowSet.java:64)
    at com.service_now.mid.probe.JDBCProbe.doSelect(JDBCProbe.java:312)
    at com.service_now.mid.probe.JDBCProbe.doQuery(JDBCProbe.java:198)
    at com.service_now.mid.probe.JDBCProbe.probe(JDBCProbe.java:123)
    at com.service_now.mid.probe.AProbe.process(AProbe.java:84)
    at com.service_now.mid.queue_worker.AWorker.runWorker(AWorker.java:125)
    at com.service_now.mid.queue_worker.AWorkerThread.run(AWorkerThread.java:20)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

i am running this from ServiceNow, DB2 Version 11

Comment: Your jdbc driver is from Db2 v9.7 fixpack 9.  Your query is valid for Db2 for LUW v11 and returns one row per user ONLY if the column-datatype of the group field is suitable.  Look at the DDL of the table, and report if the datatype of the VRAVW900_Group is  not VARCHAR or CHAR.  Otherwise you may need to SUBSTR VRAVW900_GROUP.

Comment: I don't see "cast(" in your post.  I'm guessing cast(((blah)) as varchar(100))

Answer (score 1):

Datatype of the **VRAVW900_Group** is not valid that's why the error -199.

However cast VRAVW900_Group as VARCHAR and use **LISTAGG** function for aggregating row data.

```
SELECT VRAVW900_USER,
LISTAGG(Cast(VRAVW900_Group as VARCHAR), ', ') AS Groups
FROM VRADB2.VRAVW900 
GROUP BY VRAVW900_USER
```

Check this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.2.5/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.commsql.doc/doc/r0058709.html) for usage of **LISTAGG** function.

Comment: Hi, i am getting

DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-604, SQLSTATE=42611, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.64.133

Comment: Can you tell the datatype and length for the column VRAVW900_Group

Comment: No sadly i dont have access to the database, the groups are generally between 5-10 chars

Comment: Error -604 occurs due to length or precision issue of a datatype, try using VARCHAR(10) as you said generally it is between 5-10.

Comment: ok i downloaded toad for DB2 when i run VARCHAR(10) i get:

ERROR [42884] [IBM][DB2] SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "LISTAGG" of type "" having compatible arguments was found.

Comment: Use this for reference of  LISTAGG function

`https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_listagg.html`